# FIR filter delay and window length

Tags: filters

How long does it take for FIR filter to produce first output sample for given window / kernel / impulse (not sure what is best name) length?

Does it differ between minimum phase and linear phase variants? Lets say we have two FIR low pass filters,one minimum phase,other linear phase,both have 100 sample long impulse response/window length,how long will it take to obtain first output sample?

My guess is the minimum phase needs 100 sample long delay while the linear phase 50 samples.

Answer (score 1):

For **causal** FIR linear phase filters the delay you ask for can simply be computed from the **group delay** and is given by (for an odd length symmetric FIR filter of length $L=2M+1$)
$$\tau = - \frac{d\phi(\omega)}{d\omega} = - \frac{d-M\omega}{d\omega} = M $$

So it will shift every input component by $M$ samples at the output.

**NOTE**: you can always produce your output sample $y[0]$ as soon as the first input sample $x[0]$ arrives. The **delay** is related with the information processing and not the sample processing;i.e., your initial $M-1$ output samples will be called as the filter **transient response**, before the steady output is computed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but my math skill is too low to get anything out of these equations.Could you please translate your answer into just words?

Comment: if your FIR filter is of L=101 samples long, then its group delay will be M=50 samples...

Comment: Will it be 50 no matter if it is linear phase or minimum phase?

Comment: no, it's for the linear phase filter. The minimum phase is a nonlinear phase filter, its group delay depends on frequency **yet** since it's a minimum phase filter it will produce minimum delay among all filters of similar frequency response. So your minimum phase filter should produce less delay than the linear phase one. However minimum phase filter is not an FIR filter...

Comment: FIR cant be minimum phase? In that Iowa Hill FIR software,it allows to make minimum phase FIR.

Comment: **linear phase** causal FIR filters cannot be minimum phase, because it has to maintain **symmetry** of its impulse response which is in the **middle** sample, but if you allow nonlinear phase (non-symmetric) FIR filters, then they can be mimimum phase. So there's a mistake in my generalization of minimum-phase to IIR filters. FIR can also be minimum phase (but not linear phase at the same time)

Comment: Arent all digital filter inherently FIR? Becose the digital filter impulse response have finite amount of taps/samples.I ask becose I am confused as to what is difference between digital IIR and minimum phase FIR,they both  have finite impulse response and are casual.

Comment: No. IIR = Infinite Impulse Response, its impulse response is not finite length!  An IIR filter is implemented by a **recursion** relation from its LCCDE. An FIR is implemented by the **convolution** sum of its impulse response $h[n]$...

Comment: But doesnt digital IIR filters have finite impulse response? I know theoreticaly the analog IIR filters by being in continuous reality are assumed to have infinite impulse response becose the calculations work that way but in digital discrete domain,they must have finite impulse response,it cant have infinite samples/taps...  arent then these digital IIR filter really kind of a pseudo/quasi/fake IIR filters?

Comment: the LCCDE that describe a first order IIR filter is $$y[n] = a \cdot y[n-1] + x[n] $$ has the impulse response of $$h[n] = a^n u[n]$$ It's implemented by a single tap (very simple) but its impulse response has infinite length, hene it's IIR. *Please consider a DSP review.*

Comment: I dont understand any of these equations... what is DSP review?

Comment: DSP review is the book *understanding digital signal processing* from Richard Lyons. Very readable DSP book. Please find a copy of it and read its contents.

Comment: If an IIR is stable you can in many cases, can truncate the impulse response and think of that as a FIR filter but the poles of an IIR filter are subject to round off so it can become unstable. It’s also easy to have a simple IIR filter have a very long impulse response so a FIR approximation will not be efficient and hence impractical. Treat IIR as IIR and FIR as FIR and avoid problems